# Laravel blade template and VueJs combination

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Hellow. I am learning to code with Laravel and now I am trying to do a simple SPA where user can watch/read any posts.

**Using there:** VueJs only for user's frontend part **and** Laravel blade only for Admin-panel where admin can CRUD those posts.

**Question:** How and where should we use Blade, instead VueJS which can do all stuff without Blade?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using VueJs for everything frontend and Blade for email templates that gets send to the users.